# can somebody tell me what is happening while using the extends<T extends Object> here in Getit library

Tags: dart, extends

[this image depicts the functions inside Getit package in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fAdp.png)

1 . i need to know what is the usage of T extends Object or anything comes in this format what will happen

i tried to implemnt the Getit and it is okey but , iwas eager to understand the concept inside it

Comment: `T` is a [generic](https://dart.dev/language/generics) type, and `T` is required to be a subtype of `Object` due to the `extends Object` restriction. This has the effect that `T` must be a non-nullable type because every type except for null extends `Object`. See https://dart.dev/language/generics#restricting-the-parameterized-type for more info.

Answer (score 0):

A type that conforms to `T extends Object` cannot be nullable or `dynamic`. Here is a simple example of a function `f` than can demonstrate what can be used:

```dart
T f<T extends Object>(T value) => value;
```

When calling `f`, with the generic as `dynamic` or `Object?`, you will get compile errors:

```dart
var foo = f<dynamic>(1);
// error:   ^^^^^^^
// 'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound 'Object' of the type parameter 'T'.
// Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Object'.

var bar = f<Object?>('');
// error:   ^^^^^^^
// 'Object?' doesn't conform to the bound 'Object' of the type parameter 'T'.
// Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Object'.
```

GetIt uses that type constraint so that when using their API you can correctly match the type that is stored in the service locator.